# SSL/TLS Version in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, openssl, tls

I installed Nginx and enabled SSL.

```
server {
  server_name vorb.de;
  listen      443;

  root        /var/www/vorb.de/pub;

  ssl         on;
  ssl_certificate     cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key cert.key;

  gzip        on;
  […]
}
```

Everything is working so far. The only thing that annoys me is that Chrome shows that the Server is using SSL 3.0 when you click on the lock/https icon. This version of SSL is deprecated (see https://vorb.de). When I visit an error page, everything is OK, since it shows TLS 1.0 being used (see https://vorb.de/non-existing-page). I am running Debian 6 Squeeze, Nginx 0.7.67 and OpenSSL 0.9.8o.

Do you know, why this happens?

Comment: I just want to know: Is there an outdated package, which is causing this or is this due to my certificate or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem, commenting below line helped fixing the error. Final code looked like below -

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely reinstalled my system and am using Nginx 1.0.6 now. This worked, but is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the versions allowed by the server through the use of the `ssl_ciphers` directive.

Something along these lines should get your server allowing TLS connections only:

```
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3;
```

As to why your browser negotiated different protocols on two different connections, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: When I try to do this, i get the following error:

`Restarting nginx: [emerg]:
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3") failed (SSL: error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match)
nginx.`

Answer (score 0):

Adding code between ssl_timeout and ssl_ciphers was enough to get 443 access

```
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
```

Furthermore, in my case the cert used was via openSSL so the connection wasn't necessarily "Secure" but this Did work for me

*Credits to for init ssl_protocol workaround @Soman Dubey*